# Edit XML like a sheet from Excel

Tags: text-editor, xml

I wanted to make a sheet in Excel and convert it to XML but it doesn't accept nested lists. So, I want to know if there's some software (for Linux or Windows) that shows only the information formatted after a XML Schema like Excel does (and support nested lists).

**I want to be able to edit (or insert) only the data without touching the XML tags like in Excel.**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Foxe](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm) (free firstobject XML editor):

- free
- fast to open large file
- Microsoft Windows
- can edit values:

[image]

- can insert new data, but I don't believe you can validate the XML against a  XML Schema.

Comment: I guess it could work, but it's not like I was thinking of: a more newbie-friendly interface where the XML defines the structure more like a Excel sheet and the person who will insert data doesn't need to see or interact with the source code. Thanks!

Comment: @ViniciusCoelho FWIW FOXE is **much** clearer in how the structure is, than the example in your question. I have no idea what the XML structure associated with that table should look like. Maybe edit it and put some real-world tree-structured data in it, so that it becomes clear from the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you wanted but maybe it's close. In XiMpLe editor (http://ximple.cz) you can copy/paste structured text from/to selected area. If you have some xml file

[image]

and in Excel you have cells for pasting

[image]

you can paste it over cells in xml editor...

[image]